# What does "Invalid file type chosen for conversion" mean?

Tags: docusignapi

A call to the Docusign API we've been using for a while (POST to /envelopes) has started returning an error sporadically:

```
status_code: 400
{
  "errorCode": "FORMAT_CONVERSION_ERROR_INVALID_FILE_TYPE",
  "message": "Invalid file type chosen for conversion."
}
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

That should be returned when you're attempting to upload an invalid file type via the API.

What filetype were you attempting to upload? Does your filetype and contents match?

---

### Supported File Types

> **DocuSign supports the following file types:**
>
> **DOCUMENT**  .as, .asl, .asp, .doc, .docm, .docx, .dot, .dotm, .dotx, .htm, .html, .pdf, .pdx, .rtf, .txt, .wpd, .wps, .wpt
>
> **DRAWING**   .dwg, .dxf, .emz, .svg, .svgz, .vdx, .vsd, .vss, .vst IMAGE .bmp, .cdr, .dcx, .gif, .ico, .jpg, .jpeg, .pct, .pic, .png,
>   .rgb, .sam, .tga, .tif, .tiff, .wpg
>
> **PRESENTATION**  .dps, .dpt, .pot, .potx, .pps, .ppt, .pptm, .pptx
>
> **SPREADSHEET**   .csv, .et, .ett, .xls, .xlsx, .xlt
>
> *Note: DocuSign does not support macro-enabled files. To send a macro-enabled file through DocuSign, you must first convert it to PDF
>   format.*
>
> ### File size limitations
>
> Along with the file format, DocuSign has file size limitations for
>   your file uploads:
>
> **MAXIMUM FILE SIZE** 25 MB
>
> **RECOMMENDED SIZE**  5 MB
>
> For best performance, DocuSign recommends restricting your file
>   uploads to no more than 5 MB.

[Source - DocuSign List of Supported File Types](https://www.docusign.com/support/new/documentation/ndse-help/supported-file-formats)